# Does the chessboard pattern need to remain the same after a camera has been calibrated?

Tags: matlab, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, matlab-cvst

Does the chessboard pattern need to remain constant after the camera has been calibrated?
In other words, if I calibrate with a 9x6 block board with 25mm square blocks, can I use a 32 mm square 9x6 board with the same intrinsic matrix? Does it effect the focal length, and if so, why/how?

Comment: I think it doesn't have to. Focal length of a camera only changes when you adjust camera's zoom level, otherwise it should remain the same. It is an internal parameter of a camera, that doesn't change after camera is shown another image.

Comment: the chessboards are used to *find* the intrinsic mat and distortion params. so please explain, what you're trying to do the second time.

Comment: Initially it was for calibration. Afterwards I want to calculate pose and position. But when the board gets further away, smaller blocks are harder to detect. So I want to use larger blocks. If calibrated separately, I get different focal lengths.

Answer (score 1):

Once you calibrate, you can use any checkerboard to localize your camera.  In fact, you can use any set of reference points with known 3D world coordinates, as long as you can accurately detect them in the image. The `extrinsics` function in the Computer Vision System Toolbox takes a set of image points and a set of corresponding world points, regardless of where they come from.